# Sightseeing during 12-hour stop-over at Incheon

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens

Is a Philippine passport holder allowed to leave Incheon Airport for sightseeing during a 12-hour stop-over?

Answer (score 1):

You may be allowed to leave the transit area if one or more of the following apply:

- you hold a valid South Korean visa
- you hold a diplomatic passport
- you hold a physical visa from and are traveling to or from one of the following countries: Australia, Canada, New Zealand, United States.
- you are eligible to participate in the [transit tour program](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_8_5.jsp)

I got this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea). If you believe any of the above may apply to you please double-check with the Korean embassy.